# Google Oauth 2.0 Login Authenticate failure

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authentication

I Get a code returned but when I hit the line
     $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
the script dies on that line?
How can it get any simpler?
Except for the dozens and dozens of examples that don't work, documentation errors, code examples still up on google servers that are now deprecated and do not work. etc etc etc.

```
<?php require_once ('google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php');
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret_6xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/logingoogle.php');
$client->setScopes('email');
$client->addScope('profile');

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
//echo "No Code";
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: may be adding wrong scope https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes. I know it is confusing from document point of view. what you are exactly trying to achieve? is the redirect url pointing to same code?

Comment: Just trying to get basic user authentication and email and profile scopes ?? Frankly the documentation is horrible. inconsistent,  often out of date, examples abound but appear to be often wrong. I have searched for a simple cut and past user auth with creds entered but NONE of them seem to work ??

Comment: It returns a code but he code fails when I call authenticate on client object? shouldn't it give an error not just kill the whole script if the code I pass is wrong? but the code comes from the console anyway. ???

Comment: So if you will try to run it on browser it will redirect to an authentication page where you need to click allow to proceed further, if you are trying to achieve it from console you won't be able to allow this.

Comment: No it runs the query just fine. Try it at solomonschariot[dot]com it will ask for auth, and return an auth code in the $_GET but when I submit it the code just dies on this line    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); and echo before returns but an echo line after does not. Why did you have the impression I was going after Drive ?? Did I reference the scope calls in a manner that is current ?